# How to hook into user registration process Before user registers

Tags: hooks, forms, user-meta, user-registration

I need to add a field to the user registration form and then validate it before I add a new user to my WordPress

I know how to hook into the registration form via `add_filter('register_form', 'my_function');`

But how do I hook into the registration process before the user registers? Hence I do not want `add_action('user_register','my_other_function');`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create your own hook for `registration_errors` filter:

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'wpse8170_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function wpse8170_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    if ( /* something happens */ ) {
        $errors->add( 'myexception_code', 'This is my message' );
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: im getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '10' (T_LNUMBER)`

Comment: @tq looks like you're doing something wrong. Forgot comma?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the WordPress Codex: [Customizing The Registration Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)

> Theme and plugin developers can customize WordPress's built-in user
>   registration page through the use of hooks.
>
> Customizing the registration form involves utilizing the following
>   three hooks:
>
> 1. register_form
>      Allows rendering of new HTML form elements.
> 2. registration_errors
>      Perform validation on form registration fields.
> 3. user_register
>      Save custom form data.

Comment: Haha...thanks @EugeneManuilov...I was just thinking, wait a minute isn't that pretty good documented, I guess for an answer it's a bit on the edge though.